# JavaScript set cookie via iFrame via CORS via PHP Allow Header

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, iframe, cross-domain

So I thought this would be possible, but apparently not, so far at least:

I've got domainX trying to send a secure cookie to domainY.com/page.php.  So, on domainX, I init a iframe to domainY.com/page.php with the following headers:

```
<?php
    $url = parse_url($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
    $link = $url["scheme"]."://". $url["host"];

    header('P3P:CP="We do not have a P3P Policy"');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *"); 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $link);
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
?>
```

Assuming the headers were correct.. I thought the cookie set would work i.e:

```
document.cookie = X + "=" + Y + expires + "; path=/; domain=.domainY.com; secure";
```

It does not, nor do I get any errors.  I alreaydy know my final option is **postMessage**, but is there any other way around this that anyone is aware of?

Comment: first, you can set a cookie on DomainY usin PHP, no need to js for that. Second, you can't read DomainY's cookies from DomainX. You never will.

Comment: @amenadiel I'd rather do via postMessage then PHP.  I'm trying to keep this as much front-end as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by:

Domain A stores cookie into browser, than domain A posts the data into domain B.  B catches the data and overwrites B's local cookie.